# Redux Form Validation for FieldArray in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, redux, redux-form

I'm implementing a FieldArray for the first time from redux-form and the UI works fine (although there seems some general perf implication I haven't diagnosed yet). The idea is that you click an ADD button to add another "room" to the form, which is just a text field (ignore the button component, its a custom component)

The validation code however doesn't compile. It seems I'm clashing on types, and not sure the right way to do it in typescript. I'm using guidance from [this example](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/fieldarrays/) on how to do validation, but that example is pure javascript.

The error is:

```
Type '{ _error: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | undefined'.
```

Here's the method that renders the fieldarray:

```
const renderRoomNames = (fieldProps: WrappedFieldArrayProps<string>) => (
    <Grid container spacing={4}>
      {fieldProps.fields.map((name: string, index: number) => {
        console.log('room - name', name);
        return (
          <Grid item xs={12} key={`gridroom${index + 1}`}>

            <Field            
              name={`${name}`}
              type="text"
              label={"Room " + (index + 1)}
              placeholder={`Enter a name for this room`}
              component={ReduxFormTextField}       
              required={true}
              disabled={isSuccessful}
              fullWidth      
            />
     
          </Grid>
      )})}
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <StandardButtonBase
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          startIcon={<AddIcon />}
          align="right"
          disableTooltip={true}
          round={true}
          onClick={() => fieldProps.fields.push('')}
          buttonText="Add Room"
        />
        {fieldProps.meta.submitFailed && fieldProps.meta.error && <span>{fieldProps.meta.error}</span>}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )

return (
   <FieldArray name="roomNames" component={renderRoomNames} />
)
```

And the validation code:

```
export const requestVirtualClinicFormDataValidator = (
  model?: IModel
): FormErrors<IModel> => {
  const errors: FormErrors<IModel> = {};

  if (!model) {
    errors._error = 'SNIP';
    return errors;
  }

  // General room name errors checked first
  if (isEmpty(model.roomNames) || model.roomNames.length === 0) {
    errors.roomNames = 'You require at least one room '
  } else if (model.roomNames.some((x) => isEmpty(x))) {
    errors.roomNames = { _error: 'All room names must have a value' };
  } else {
    // Specific individual room name checks second
    const roomNameErrors:any[] = [];

    if (model.roomNames.length === 1 && isEmpty(model.roomNames[0])) {
      roomNameErrors[0] = { _error: 'You must provide a name for your room' };     
    } else {        
      for (let i=0; i < model.roomNames.length; i++) {
        const roomName = model.roomNames[i];
        const count = model.roomNames.filter(x => x.toLowerCase() === roomName.toLowerCase()).length;
        if (count > 1) {
          roomNameErrors[i] = { _error: 'All rooms must have a unique name' }
        }
      }
      
      if (roomNameErrors && roomNameErrors.length > 0) {
        errors.roomNames = roomNameErrors;
      }
    }
  }

  return errors;
};
```

The problem is at compilation. It doesn't like the `_error:`  part, it wants a straight string.

However it also won't allow the line `errors.roomNames = roomNameErrors;` if leaving roomNameErrors as a string array. That instead results in this error:

```
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | undefined'.
```

It seems that even though 'roomNames' property on my model is a string array, the type definition for this wants react component or string only. How do I pass back validation failures for a given field within the field array, using typescript? The example linked earlier simply doesn't pass typescript typings as they are currently setup.

Using redux-form 8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the type definitions were indeed wrong.
By switching the errors from FormErrors to type Any, it all compiled, and actually worked. I will log an issue with the definitely typed repo to fix this.

Comment: Hi, thx for your own answer. If you had time to put the issue on Github could you link it here ? Thx !